# SKSpriteNode Hero sometimes not able to cross Sprite edges

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm developing a 2D platform game with SpriteKit. Inside my scenes update method I apply an impulse to my hero when he should move forwards or backwards

```
heroPhysicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,heroPhysicsBody.velocity.dy)
heroPhysicsBody.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(CGFloat(moveDirection)*680,0))
```

I placed two equivalent platforms next to each other in my game.

Everything works fine but when my hero should move from platform A to platform B (in other words: cross the edge of both platforms) he sometimes stops at slightly different positions around that edge! I'm always able to go back and sometimes its successful to cross the edge after going back. It seems to occur totally arbitrary.

Jumping over the edge always works.

[image that shows the platforms and the problematic edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNLo1.png)

[original platform png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYNhH.png)

In a debug session I could confirm that when my hero is mysteriously occupied the "moving force" is still being applied and that he has the expected "moving velocity".

My platforms physics body:

```
    floorGrass.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: floorGrassTexture, size: floorGrass.size)
    floorGrass.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    floorGrass.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
    floorGrass.physicsBody!.friction = 1
    floorGrass.physicsBody!.mass = 10
    floorGrass.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Platform
    floorGrass.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.None
    floorGrass.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.None
```

My heros physics body

```
    pbody.affectedByGravity = true
    pbody.mass = 5
    pbody.linearDamping = 1
    pbody.friction = 1
    pbody.restitution = 0
    pbody.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    pbody.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Character
    pbody.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Platform | PhysicsCategories.Flame | PhysicsCategories.Stachelfalle | PhysicsCategories.Bamboostick
    pbody.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Platform | PhysicsCategories.Stachelfalle | PhysicsCategories.Blocker
```

Thanks

Comment: what physics body is applied to the platforms?

Comment: try a fromPoint-toPoint physicsBody. you don't really need a rectangle

Comment: Great, a point to point body works ! Thanks! But I still have no clue why it does not work with the shape that is generated from my texture. (I added the original png to my post)

Comment: maybe because on the size of the physics body you need to go over the textures-size property like: floorGrass.texture.frame.size or floorGrass.texture.size.